# Explicitly handle gzipped json before binding

Tags: json, go, gzip, go-gin

I want to write an api that will be sent gzipped json data with POST. While the below can deal with simple json in the body, it does not deal if the json is gzipped.

Do we need to explicitly handle the decompression before using `c.ShouldBindJSON`?

### How to reproduce

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.POST("/postgzip", func(c *gin.Context) {
        
        type PostData struct {
            Data string `binding:"required" json:"data"`
        }
        
        var postdata PostData
        if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&postdata); err != nil {
            log.Println("Error parsing request body", "error", err)
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
            return
        }
        log.Printf("%s", postdata)
        if !c.IsAborted() {
            c.String(200, postdata.Data)
        }
    })
    r.Run()
}
```

```
❯ echo '{"data" : "hello"}' | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- localhost:8080/postgzip
hello
```

### Expectations

```
$ echo '{"data" : "hello"}' | gzip | curl -v -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --data-binary @- localhost:8080/postgzip
hello
```

### Actual result

```
$ echo '{"data" : "hello"}' | gzip | curl -v -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --data-binary @- localhost:8080/postgzip
{"error":"invalid character '\\x1f' looking for beginning of value"}
```

### Environment

- go version: `go version go1.17.2 darwin/amd64`
- gin version (or commit ref): `v1.7.4`
- operating system: MacOS Monterey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we need to explicitly handle the decompression before using c.ShouldBindJSON ?

Of course. Gin `ShouldBindJSON` knows nothing of how your payload may or may not be encoded. [It expects JSON input](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/binding/json.go#L44), as the method name suggests.

If you wish to write reusable code, you can implement the [`Binding`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/binding#Binding) interface.

A very minimal example:

```
type GzipJSONBinding struct {
}

func (b *GzipJSONBinding) Name() string {
    return "gzipjson"
}

func (b *GzipJSONBinding) Bind(req *http.Request, dst interface{}) error {
    r, err := gzip.NewReader(req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    raw, err := io.ReadAll(r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(raw, dst)
}
```

And then usable with [`c.ShouldBindWith`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4#Context.ShouldBindWith), which allows using an arbitrary binding engine:

```
err := c.ShouldBindWith(&postData, &GzipJSONBinding{})
```

Comment: It would probably also probably be a good idea to switch on the Content-Encoding header right?

Comment: @Moulick yeah, not in the binding though. You should check the headers in the handler, before calling `ShouldBindWith`

Comment: also then what's the point of the net/http compression, Does it also not handle some type of compressions as like it literally has a DisableCompression bool ?
https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport

Comment: @Moulick `http.Transport` and its compression options are relevant to making requests, i.e. in the http **client**. Here you are implementing a server

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll attach the full working code to this answer for anyone in the future

Answer (score 0):

## Fully working example that switches on `Content-Encoding`

curl to try to use it

```
$ echo '{"data" : "hello"}' | gzip | curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --data-binary @- localhost:8080/json
hello
```

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{"data" : "hello"}' localhost:8080/json
hello
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type PostData struct {
    Data string `binding:"required" json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/json", func(c *gin.Context) {

        var postdata PostData

        contentEncodingHeader := c.GetHeader("Content-Encoding")
        switch contentEncodingHeader {
        case "gzip":
            if err := c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&postdata, gzipJSONBinding{}); err != nil {
                log.Println("Error parsing GZIP JSON request body", "error", err)
                c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
                return
            }
        case "":
            if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&postdata); err != nil {
                log.Println("Error parsing JSON request body", "error", err)
                c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
                return
            }
        default:
            log.Println("unsupported Content-Encoding")
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "unsupported Content-Encoding"})
            return

        }

        log.Printf("%s", postdata)
        if !c.IsAborted() {
            c.String(200, postdata.Data)
        }
    })
    r.Run()
}

type gzipJSONBinding struct{}

func (gzipJSONBinding) Name() string {
    return "gzipjson"
}

func (gzipJSONBinding) Bind(req *http.Request, obj interface{}) error {
    if req == nil || req.Body == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid request")
    }
    r, err := gzip.NewReader(req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    raw, err := io.ReadAll(r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(raw, obj)
}

func (gzipJSONBinding) BindBody(body []byte, obj interface{}) error {
    r, err := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(body))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return decodeJSON(r, obj)
}

func decodeJSON(r io.Reader, obj interface{}) error {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r)

    if err := decoder.Decode(obj); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return validate(obj)
}

func validate(obj interface{}) error {
    if binding.Validator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return binding.Validator.ValidateStruct(obj)
}
```